# Is there a classification of 2d extended TQFTs with defects?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft, symmetric-monoidal-categories

[Chris Schommer-Pries](https://mathoverflow.net/users/184/chris-schommer-pries) has classified 2d extended TQFTs ([topological quantum field theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory)) in his [PhD thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1000v2). The result is a (not necessarily abelian) separable symmetric Frobenius algebra (possibly internal to some symmetric monoidal category).

What if we add defects into the game? I couldn't find a hard classification result for 2d extended TQFTs with defects. Is there one? Or at least a folk theorem? Does the classification of extended TQFTs without defects somehow follow as a special case?

EDIT: If there are hints on how the classification for non-extended 2d TQFTs (2-1-TQFTs, so to speak) with defects goes, that would be relevant too.

Comment: Does "with defects" mean something different than "with singularities"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I think this is regarded to be the same. For simplicity, we could leave point defects out for the time being and just ask for TQFTs with line defects. Then the lines should just be submanifolds.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thinking about it again, defects are probably more than just singularities. Looking at http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.0495v1.pdf, it seems that defects should actually give morphisms of TQFTs.